# Linq using predicate not working

Tags: asp.net, linq

I've created a small test class, that returns data from an xml file.

I now want to make it more dynamic using linq but cannot get it to work.

```
public class LenderCollection
{
    string fileName = "C:\\Lenders.xml";

    public IEnumerable<Lender> Lenders { get; set; }

    public void FetchLenders(Expression<Func<Lender, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
        IEnumerable<Lender> lenders = XmlHelper.GetObjectFromXml<List<Lender>>(fileName, "AllLenders");

        Lenders =  predicate.IsNotNull() ? lenders.Where(predicate) : lenders;

    }
}
```

Visual Studio is giving an error on the section "lenders.Where(predicate)" - the message is "... does not contain a definition for Where..."

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

*** UPDATE ***

It seems to be something to do with the predicate - .Where is avaialable otherwise.

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Linq.Expressions;` at the top of your file

Comment: @Andomar - already included

Comment: BTW, you should always post the entire exception message. While sometimes long and hard to read, it will probably already contain the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no extension method `Where` that extends `IEnumerable<T>` and takes a parameter of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

You have two options:

1. Use an `IQueryable<Lender>` instead of `IEnumerable<Lender>` (you can this easily by just calling `.AsQueryable()`) if you wan to keep the parameter `predicate` as `Expression<Func<Lender, bool>>`
2. Use the type `Func<Lender, bool>` instead of `Expression<Func<Lender, bool>>` for the `predicate` parameter. Since you're loading your data from a file, there's no point in using an `IQueryable` over an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thanks dominic - both work, however I used 2 for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining that whatever type `lenders` is does not have a `.Where` method. This is either because:

- You haven't included `using System.Linq;`
- The type of `lenders` isn't an `IEnumerable` or similar.

Comment: Aleady includes linq namespace - See above - variable lenders is IEnumerable<Lender>

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
lenders.Where(predicate)
```

With:

```
lenders.ToList().Where(predicate)
```

Both should be able to return `IEnumerable`.

The main downfall with this is that the query will execute on the `.ToList()` command. I guess this is down to what you expect your function to be doing though, and if this is acceptable for your needs.